# No imprime el valor de x y el 0, en Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Construir un functor denominado decrementa/2, tal que dado un número X, se forme
una lista que decremente en 1 hasta llegar a 0.

```
decrementa(5,S).
```

> S=[5,4,3,2,1,0]

### Intentos

```
decrementa(1, []) :- !.
decrementa(X, [S|Resto]) :- X > 1, S is X-1, 
decrementa(S, Resto).
```

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Comment: decrementa(1, []) :- ! .
decrementa(X, [S|Resto]) :-
  X > 1,
  S is X-1,
  decrementa(S, Resto).

Comment: eso hice hasta ahora pero no me imprime el valor de x y el 0

Answer (score 0):

Esta curioso tu ejercicio. Una amnera de resolverlo es:

```
decrementa(1, false, []) :- !.
decrementa(X, false, [S|Resto]) :- X > 1,
    S is X-1,
    decrementa(S, false,Resto)
    .
decrementa(X, true, [X,S|Resto]) :- X > 1,
    S is X-1,
    decrementa(S, false,Resto)
    .

decrementa(X,List):- decrementa(X,true,List).
```

Primero observe que solo la primera vez queremos concatenar el elemento inicial al resto de la lista, asi que el segundo parametro nos sirve justamente para eso, y el resto de las invocaciones recursivas nos llevaran al caso que ya tenias descubierto.
No se que tan antural sea esta solucion, pero conserva tu pensamiento recursivo.

Otra cosa que puedes notar es que uso tanto la barra vertical como la coma, la barra vertical nos ayuda a indicar el resto y la coma una enumeracion, por lo que podemos usar ambos apra obtener los primeros n elementos que deseemos y la barra vertical para indicar el resto de la lista por ejemplo

```
[primero,segundo,tercero,cuarto|resto]
```

Si hacemos un trace obtendremos:

```
Call: (20) decrementa(5, _40846) ? creep
   Call: (21) decrementa(5, true, _40846) ? creep
   Call: (22) 5>1 ? creep
   Exit: (22) 5>1 ? creep
   Call: (22) _42800 is 5-1 ? creep
   Exit: (22) 4 is 5-1 ? creep
   Call: (22) decrementa(4, false, _42802) ? creep
   Call: (23) 4>1 ? creep
   Exit: (23) 4>1 ? creep
   Call: (23) _46586 is 4-1 ? creep
   Exit: (23) 3 is 4-1 ? creep
   Call: (23) decrementa(3, false, _46588) ? creep
   Call: (24) 3>1 ? creep
   Exit: (24) 3>1 ? creep
   Call: (24) _50372 is 3-1 ? creep
   Exit: (24) 2 is 3-1 ? creep
   Call: (24) decrementa(2, false, _50374) ? creep
   Call: (25) 2>1 ? creep
   Exit: (25) 2>1 ? creep
   Call: (25) _54158 is 2-1 ? creep
   Exit: (25) 1 is 2-1 ? creep
   Call: (25) decrementa(1, false, _54160) ? creep
   Exit: (25) decrementa(1, false, []) ? creep
   Exit: (24) decrementa(2, false, [1]) ? creep
   Exit: (23) decrementa(3, false, [2, 1]) ? creep
   Exit: (22) decrementa(4, false, [3, 2, 1]) ? creep
   Exit: (21) decrementa(5, true, [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) ? creep
   Exit: (20) decrementa(5, [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) ? creep
```

Answer (score 0):

El procedimiento se resuelve recursivamente de la siguiente manera:

*Paso base*: cuando el item actual es 0 se coloca como único elemento de la lista y se termina la recursión

*Paso recursivo*: Si el número es mayor a 0, se coloca como elemento en la lista y se llama recursivamente pasándo como parámetro el número menos 1.

```
decrementa(0, [0]).
decrementa(X, [X|D]):-
  X > 0, % guarda
  X1 is X-1,
  decrementa(X1, D).
```

Ejemplo:

```
?- decrementa(5, L).
L = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0] ;
false.
```

Esa implementación deja una alternativa abierta en el paso base, que luego al intentar buscar una segunda solución no encuentra y nos indica `false`.
Para evitarlo debemos hacer uso del indizado que hace el motor de prolog reificando la comparación y utilizando un procedimiento auxiliar:

```
decrementa(X, D):-
  compare(C, X, 0),
  decrementa(C, X, D).
  
decrementa((=), X, [X]).
decrementa((>), X, [X|D]):-
  X1 is X-1,
  decrementa(X1, D).
```

Ahora obtenemos:

```
?- decrementa(5, L).
L = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0].
```

que sucede sin dejar alternativas abiertas.